# Is there a way to add a new database to a linked server automatically every time it is created by an application?

Tags: sql-server

I have a linked server accessing some databases on server A from Server B.. An application creates a new database on server A once a month so I want to be able to automatically add the newly created database to the linked server.

I am quite new to linked servers so I haven't been able to find anything online

I expect to have the newly created databases added automatically to the linked server

Comment: Using the comments on my answer this has changed significantly. What you are looking for is a database trigger. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You don't add databases to a linked server. The linked server references the remote server. Your code then defines which database you query from with four part naming.

```
[LinkedServer].[Database].[schema].[object]
```

Comment: I am sorry i think i asked the question wrong. I was supposed to ask ‘ how do automate the process of adding a new database to an existing login used for linked server’

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Are you saying you are adding a new database to a server and you want to provide access to this database automatically? I don't see how the linked server comes into play there. Maybe I am missing something though.

Comment: Yes you are correct . An application creates a new database on server A every month. So i want to automatically grant read only access to the login i use for linked server to access the new database on server b

Comment: You should be doing that by role. And when you create the new database you would update the role to allow read only access.

Comment: An application creates the new database so I can’t add a script to update the role. So i am looking for a script to put in a job to update the role whenever the new database is created

Comment: Deleting this as the question has changed significantly.